# How to return a Button from a function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I need to dynamically create a Button based on some parameters

```swift
func buildButton(parameter : Parameter) -> Button {
        switch (parameter){
            case Parameter.Value1:
                return Button(
                    action: {
                        ...
                },
                    label: {
                        ...
                }
            )
            case Parameter.Value2:
                return Button(
                    action: {...},
                    label: {
                        ...
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

But the compiler gives me this error:

> Reference to generic type 'Button' requires arguments in <...>. Insert '<<#Label: View#>>'

So if I click `Fix`, the function declaration becomes

```swift
func buildButton(parameter : Parameter) -> Button<Label:View>
```

and the compiler gives

> Use of undeclared type '<#Label: View#>'

What do I need to insert here to be able to return a `Button`?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not sure how important it is that you get a Button, but if you just need it to be displayed in another SwiftUI View without further refinements, you can just return `some View`. You only have to embed all your Buttons in AnyView's.

```swift
func buildButton(parameter : Parameter) -> some View {
        switch (parameter){
            case Parameter.Value1:
                return AnyView(Button(
                    action: {
                        ...
                },
                    label: {
                        ...
                })
            )
            case Parameter.Value2:
                return AnyView(Button(
                    action: {...},
                    label: {
                        ...
                })
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Comeing from a Flutter/React Native background, if I need to just return a widget/component I can declare a return type of `some View` in  the function declaration, with a component wrapped in `AnyView`

Comment: As of Xcode 12 at least I found that I did not need to embed the Button in AnyView.  Works fine without it, so code is a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the declaration of `Button`, you can see that it is a generic `struct`, so you need to supply its generic type parameter.

```
struct Button<Label> where Label : View
```

Make sure that you replace `YourView` with the actual type implementing `View` that you want to return.

```
class YourView: View { ... }

func buildButton(parameter : Parameter) -> Button<YourView> {
    switch (parameter){
        case Parameter.Value1:
            return Button(
                action: {
                    ...
            },
                label: {
                    ...
            }
        )
        case Parameter.Value2:
            return Button(
                action: {...},
                label: {
                    ...
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've understood. I've renamed <YourView> with the name of struct the Button is in. Now I have a different problem: 
if I try to insert an Image as label, 
`label: {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").foregroundColor(App.Colors.NavBar.Foreground)
                }
`
compiler gives error `Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to closure result type 'YourView'`