# Type of Expression is ambiguous when returning some View

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to return a button view from a function in swiftui. While trying to follow the instructions here: [How to return a Button from a function in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322631/how-to-return-a-button-from-a-function-in-swiftui)

I am getting error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. Which when searching, seems to be a very vague error.

```
func sheetButton(action: () ->Void, title: String) -> some View {
return Button(action: action, label: title)
}
```

I also tried wrapping Button in AnyView, and had the same error. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correctly call the button and @escaping action like that

```
func sheetButton(action: @escaping () ->Void, title: String) -> some View {
    Button(title, action: action)
}
```